# Импорт библиотеки в Java

Tags: java, импорт

Не получается сделать импорт библиотеки `ArrayUtils`. При импорте возникает ошибка `error: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist`. Импортирую с помощью

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
```

На сайте с документацией `apache.org` в начале написано название библиотеки и что-то типа адреса к ней:

> org.apache.commons.lang3
>
> Class ArrayUtils
>
> java.lang.Object
>
> extended by org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils

Что из этого должно помочь подключить и использовать библиотеку в моем коде?

Comment: вам сначала нужно добавить файл библиотеки к проекту, как это сделать зависит от среды и типа проекта

Comment: Ну а например библиотеку Arrays можно просто импортировать. Как понять, когда библиотека сторонняя, а когда ее можно просто подключить?

Comment: @FedotSoldier если пакет начинается с `java.` или `javax.`, значит он входит в стандартную библиотеку. Если нет, то не входит, за редкими исключениями.

Comment: если вылетает ошибка - значит библиотека сторонняя

Comment: А если, сторонняя, то все-таки нельзя поподробнее о том, как ее подключить? При учете, что у меня один файл с кодом

Comment: так добавьте в вопрос какую среду разработки используете, тогда и расскажем

Comment: Как среда разработки влияет на подключение? Я просто этот язык только начал учить и решаю задачи в блокноте. Компиляция через `javac`

Comment: Установите Intellij idea, это бесплатная среда разработки, один раз разберетесь, многое сразу станет более проще делать.

Comment: Хочется, чтобы не среда все делала за тебя, а было понятно, что происходит, особенно для начального понимания. Но по поводу среды разработки я посмотрю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> А если, сторонняя, то все-таки нельзя поподробнее о том, как ее
>   подключить?

Скачиваете jar-файл в любое удобное место и передаёте путь к нему в ключе [-cp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCDIFEE) компилятора:

```
javac -cp /path/to/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar MyClass.java
```

> Хочется, чтобы не среда все делала за тебя, а было понятно, что
>   происходит

Читать про CLASSPATH, загрузчики классов и пакеты. Лучше всего читать из учебника.

Comment: А если в CLASSPATH прописать путь до библиотеки, будет работать import ?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду переменную окружения CLASSPATH?

Comment: Ну да. Которая в переменных среды. А какая еще CLASSPATH есть?

Comment: CLASSPATH - это место, в котором компилятор и виртуальная машина ищут классы. Одноимённая переменная окружения - это только один из способов его задать. Кстати, это способ нерекомендуемый. Лучше использовать ключ командной строки `-cp`.

Comment: Спасибо. А с чем связана "нерекомендуемость" данного способа

Comment: Потому что у каждого проекта свои зависимости и должен быть свой CLASSPATH, а переменная окружения может быть задана на уровне системы или пользователя. Глобальный CLASSPATH неизбежно приводит к _jar hell_.